# How to remove space and return symbols in Xcode setting

Tags: xcode11

I have been using Xcode to edit Python code. However, after recent update to version 11.1, I found the unwanted >>... signs between the code. I tried to get rid of it by fiddling with Xcode/Preferences but to no avail. How do I turn off these space/return symbols?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Editor -> Invisibles, Make sure it is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem. I had thought it must be some setting in Preferences, but it turned out to be under Editor.

Comment: You're welcome @Chenyang, Please mark the answer as best, if it has helped.